# Keep text aligned top and image aligned to the bottom of relative height divs

Tags: css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have 4 columns of products with a header, description and image below and I want the text areas to at the top and the images to each line up at the bottom so they stay aligned when the screen is resized.

At the moment the images move up and down as the text wraps - which looks very untidy as they each have a different amount of text.

I have tried using tables and position absolute and they each cause problems and don't work properly.

Here is my code:

```css
#product-landing .landing-row {
  position: relative;
  height: inherit;
}

.product-landing,
.product-landing-2,
.product-landing-3 {
  margin-right: 2.0533%;
}

.product-landing,
.product-landing-2,
.product-landing-3,
.product-landing-4 {
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 22.978%;
}

.product-landing-4 {
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#product-landing p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-landing .land-image {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.product-landing img,
.product-landing-2 img,
.product-landing-3 img,
.product-landing-4 img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-landing">
  <div class="landing-row">
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product1</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image1.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing-2">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product2</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image2.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing-3">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product3</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image3.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing-4">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product4</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image4.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this

```css
#product-landing .landing-row {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#product-landing p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.product-landing {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: 22.978%;
}

.product-landing img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 350px;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-text {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-landing">
  <div class="landing-row">
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div class="product-text">
        <div class="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product1</a></div>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div class="product-text">
        <div class="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product2</a></div>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div class="product-text">
        <div class="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product2</a></div>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div class="product-text">
        <div class="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product3</a></div>
        <p><b><i>Product description Product description Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div class="product-text">
        <div class="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product4</a></div>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Nope.  As soon as the text wraps on one of the columns (when the screen is resized) the images go out of alignment.  They are still aligning to the bottom of the text rather than the product-landing box.

Comment: @LouiseW what browser are you using - this works fine in edge, ie, chrome and firefox - are you saying it doesn't work in your code or that the above code doesn't work as when I run the snippet and use the full page and resize the screen, the images always stay aligned.  You may note that I have changed your invalid ids (ids must be unique) to classes and changed your weird id like classes to use one class.  The snippet clearly works so it must be something in your code

Comment: Yes I have changed the ids to classes as you did in your code.  I am using the latest version of Chrome and Firefox.  I have also checked safari, yandex, opera and IE 10 and older browsers and it does the same.  Bear in mind there is a lot more description text than is shown here, it varies between 1 and 4 lines.

Comment: Can you  make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your new code so I can see what you have done as clearly something is wrong as the above will work in all browsers (apart from safari which may has flex issues)

Comment: I have made the fiddle here (I hope this is right): https://jsfiddle.net/louiseW/ozjkzr7k/

Comment: You need to indent your code properly, but you have invalid html and you have moved the image inside the text div - as that is the div that grows to fill the space, it is obviously not going to work with the image in there.  You also seem to have completely ignored the product-landing class in my snippet. So yes my code does work, nope your implementation of it is rubbish

Comment: Thanks, that does work now.  I don't know what you meant by "you have moved the image inside the text div" as I clearly hadn't, and I had a good reason for the product-landing classes being numbered which involves other parts of the site that uses it.

Comment: If you have a look at your fiddle and press the tidy button, your code will be indented nicely and you will see that your image p is inside your product-text div, it should be after it, I should also point out that b and i tags aren't to be used for bold and italic anymore - they have a different semantic meaning now, you should be using strong and em.  You can keep your product number classes - just give them all a general class too, the point of a class is that it is general so to add a separate class for each box even though they share styles is completely against how css should be used

Answer (score 0):

Would've commented this if I could; Have you tried using flex-box? 
 https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

This has saved me on many occasions where relative/absolute combinations fail.

To be more specific;

```
    .wrapper{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    .text-wrapper-div{
        align-self:flex-start;
    }
    .image-wrapper-div{
        align-self:flex-end;
    }
```

.wrapper is your parent-container, which flexes from top to bottom (column).
Inside are the two div's for text and image, which align themselves to the top (flex-start) and bottom (flex-end).

Have a look at the link if you get stuck - it's pretty well documented I think! Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I still couldn't get the images to align using this method.  Also it doesn't work with older browsers and looks terrible when I tested it on one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you,

Using flex is considered to be best practice. The table and table-cell are the old ways as we have came way far and new properties are being invented day by day. As using the flex will adjust the content itself as you resize the browser and has its own qualities.

```css
#product-landing .landing-row {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.product-landing,
.product-landing-2,
.product-landing-3 {
  margin-right: 2.0533%;
}

.product-landing,
.product-landing-2,
.product-landing-3,
.product-landing-4 {
    flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}


#product-landing p {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-landing .land-image {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.product-landing img,
.product-landing-2 img,
.product-landing-3 img,
.product-landing-4 img {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-landing">
  <div class="landing-row">
    <div class="product-landing">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product1</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image1.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing-2">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product2</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image2.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing-3">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product3</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image3.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="product-landing-4">
      <div id="product-text">
        <div id="offer-title"><a href="/address" target="_blank">Product4</a></div>
        <p>
        </p>
        <p><b><i>Product description</i></b></p>
      </div>
      <p class="land-image">
        <a href="/address" target="_blank"><img src="http://image4.jpg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```